# Incrementing NULL pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, null, undefined-behavior

If I incrementing `NULL` pointer in C, then What happens?

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
        int x;
        int y;
        int z;
}st;

int main(void)
{
        st *ptr = NULL;
        ptr++; //Incrementing null pointer 
        printf("%d\n", (int)ptr);
        return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
12
```

Is it **undefined behavior**? If **No**, then **Why**?

Comment: More importantly, why would you ever do such a thing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The behaviour is always undefined. You can never own the memory at NULL.

Pointer arithmetic is only valid within arrays, and you can set a pointer to an index of the array or one location beyond the final element. Note I'm talking about setting a pointer here, not dereferencing it.

You can also set a pointer to a scalar and one past that scalar.

You can't use pointer arithmetic to traverse other memory that you own.

Comment: The Standard does not specify a behavior, but some implementations do.  For example, Keil's compiler for the ARM documents that for *any* `char*p,*q; int i;`, the expression `p+i` will be equivalent to `(char*)( ((uintptr_t)p) +i)`, and `p-q` will be equivalent to `(ptrdiff_t)( ((uintptr_t)p)-((uintptr_t)q))`, and such equivalence is not dependent upon whether the Standard would require defined behavior in any particular case.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Any operator needs a "valid" operand, a `NULL` is not one for the post increment operator.

Quoting `C11`, [chapter §6.5.2.4](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.4)

> The result of the postfix `++` operator is the value of the operand. As a side effect, the
>   value of the operand object is incremented (that is, the value 1 of the appropriate type is
>   added to it). [....]

and related to additive operators, §6.5.6

> For addition, either both operands shall have arithmetic type, or one operand shall be a
>   pointer to a complete object type and the other shall have integer type. (Incrementing is
>   equivalent to adding 1.)

then, P7,

> [...] a pointer to an object that is not an element of an
>   array behaves the same as a pointer to the first element of an array of length one with the
>   type of the object as its element type.

and, P8,

> If the pointer operand points to an element of
>   an array object, and the array is large enough, the result points to an element offset from
>   the original element such that the difference of the subscripts of the resulting and original
>   array elements equals the integer expression. In other words, if the expression `P` points to
>   the `i`-th element of an array object, the expressions `(P)+N` (equivalently, `N+(P)`) and
>   `(P)-N` (where `N` has the value `n`) point to, respectively, the `i+n`-th and `i−n`-th elements of
>   the array object, provided they exist. [....] If both the pointer
>   operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last
>   element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; **otherwise, the
>   behavior is undefined.**

Comment: Could you add a link to the quote items?

Comment: @luoluo Well, the actual standard is (for some weird reason) not free and open-source (the money does not go to the contributors!!). We can find many draft versions online, let me add one to my answer.

Comment: The mummys and daddys at ISO have kids to feed you know.

Comment: @Bathsheba well, so do the contributors. Why'd we assume anything different? At the end of the day, we're all trying to make two ends meet.

Answer (score 0):

In your example you didn't dereferenced the pointer just printed out the address it points to. When you step a pointer, it will be incremented whith the size of it's reference type. Just try:

```
printf("Test: %lu", sizeof(st));
```

And you will get `Test: 12` as output. If you would dereference it, like `*ptr`, it will cause an **undefined behavior**.

Comment: No it's UB even without the dereference.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Can you further explain what all can happen as part of UB. I guess UB is w.r.t to program logic. Since the pointer do not points to valid or meaningful  area of memory, so from programming logic development point of view this seems ambiguous or not clear as to what the person is trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I think ptr will point to the second array member (as if there were) of `struct st`. Thats what `ptr++` does. Initially pointer was at 0 or `NULL`. Now it is at 12 (`3 * sizeof(int)` = 3*4 = 12).

Comment: Yes that is a very plausible explanation but note that formally the program behaviour is undefined.